# Concurrent start with async/await

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

I thought I had a pretty good understanding of async await until I tried this:

```js
const promise1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => resolve('what'), 10000);
});

const promise2 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => resolve('?'), 15000);
});

async function asyncTest() {
  console.time();
  const p1 = await promise1;

  if (p1 === 'what') {
    var p2 = await promise2;
  }

  console.log(p1, p2);
  console.timeEnd();
}

asyncTest()
```

After 15000ms, `asyncTest` is logging `p1` & `p2`. If instead `promise1` and `promise2` are transformed into functions that return these promises, execution time is then 25000ms. I have no idea what's going on. Could anyone care to explain this?

Comment: I'd never even heard of https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/timeEnd Cool!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issues is that your Promise callbacks are invoked immediately after you declare them.

```
const promise1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => resolve('what'), 10000);
});

const promise2 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => resolve('?'), 15000);
});
```

At this point, both callbacks have been invoked. 10000ms from this point, `promise1` will resolve. 15000ms from this point, `promise2` will resolve.

```
async function asyncTest() {
  console.time();
  const p1 = await promise1;

  if (p1 === 'what') {
    var p2 = await promise2;
  }

  console.log(p1, p2);
  console.timeEnd();
}

asyncTest()
```

At this point, as both callbacks have already been invoked, both will be resolved within 15000ms, which is what you observed.

In order to stretch this to the 25000ms you were expecting, try rewriting the Promises as follows:

```
const promise1 = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => resolve('what'), 10000);
});

const promise2 = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => resolve('?'), 15000);
});
```

Note these are now function expressions that will not be invoked immediately. Then rewrite your `asyncTest` function to invoke these expressions instead of simply await the already executing Promises:

```
async function asyncTest() {
  console.time();
  const p1 = await promise1();

  if (p1 === 'what') {
    var p2 = await promise2();
  }

  console.log(p1, p2);
  console.timeEnd();
}
```

This will force `promise2` to wait until `promise1` is completed before beginning execution.

Answer (score 1):

With the code in its current state:

You run `setTimeout` and assign a promise that will handle its result to `promise1`. Immediately after, you do the same thing for `promise2`.

So promise2 resolves about five seconds after promise1.

---

If you change the code so that `promise1` and `promise2` are functions, then:

You run `setTimeout` return a promise that will handle its result to `await`. It will wait until the promise resolves 10 seconds later. Then it will assign the result to `p1`.

Then (i.e. after 10 seconds have passed instead of immediately) it will do the same thing for `p2`.

---

In short:

In the first example, you don't wait for promise1 before setting promise2 going.

After making the change you describe, you do `await` promise1 before setting promise2 going.

Comment: Why did you rollback the added snippet? I was about to upvote for it.

Comment: @Zenoo — It bloated the answer without being useful. If anything, it should have been edited into the question, not my answer.

Comment: Maybe you could include it in a hidden snippet at the end? I really feel like it added some clarification.

Comment: You're sort of explaining the problem correctly but in a way that I believe adds more confusion. The issue is that both `promise1` and `promise2` are triggered prior `asyncTest()` being invoked at all. It has nothing to do with the use of `setTimeout` internally.

Answer (score 1):

In the first example, two promises fire-off instantly at the beginning, and by the time when browser executes line `var p2 = await promise2;` the promise2 is on-half way to resolve and `await` statement pauses for 5000 ms.

```js
console.log('promise1 created');
const promise1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => resolve('what'), 10000);
});

console.log('promise2 created');
const promise2 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => resolve('?'), 15000);
});

async function asyncTest() {
  console.time();
  const p1 = await promise1;

  if (p1 === 'what') {
    var p2 = await promise2;
  }

  console.log(p1, p2);
  console.timeEnd();
}

asyncTest();
```

In the second example, you fire promises only when browser reaches the line where the function firing promise is called. So at line `var p2 = await promise2();` the second promise is created and `await` statement pauses for 15000 ms. Thus total execution time is 25000 ms.

```js
const promise1 = () => {
  console.log('promise1 created');
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve('what'), 10000);
  })
};


const promise2 = () => {
  console.log('promise2 created');
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve('?'), 15000);
  })
};

async function asyncTest() {
  console.time();
  const p1 = await promise1();

  if (p1 === 'what') {
    var p2 = await promise2();
  }

  console.log(p1, p2);
  console.timeEnd();
}

asyncTest();
```

Comment: There aren't two examples. OP seems to have believed that `await`ing the result would trigger the Promise constructor callback. The problem is that this callback is invoked immediately after instantiation for both Promises, thus, the 15000ms execution.

Comment: Ahh, now there are two examples :)